# I need to create a python program that will calculate maximum, average and minimum

Tags: python, list, max, average, min

Let me give you a bit of context. I am supposed to create a program that will read a list from the keyboard, then calculate the maximum, minimum and average of the values given. Then, it needs to print the results in a list form. 
I have no idea how to start this.

Comment: Maybe a python tutorial would be a good place to start.

Comment: learning python may be a good start.

Comment: `I am supposed to create a program` Off you go then...

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to get an input from the shell maybe using a while loop, than you can append that too an array, and index to the array while adding up every number that was entered from the console in the array. than you get a for loop to loop through the array set a integer variable or a float variable depending on the types that you are working on. one set as max that equals to 0 if you are entering non-negative integers or floating numbers, after that check if that number is smaller or bigger than the current number at the current index. if it is bigger change the max from 0 to the current indexed number by assigning it to the max variable that you initialized before the for loop. do the inverse to collect the min. This basically a design that you can use. If this does not help feel free to comment below I am done with my work will be on here for another hour or so. So feel free to comment below I will be glad to help out. :-) Happy coding.